# Server Fault Conference

Tags: discussion

I’m excited to announce that Server Fault will be hosting a one day educational conference for system administrators and other network operations professionals.  This conference will be supported by [HighScalability.com](http://highscalability.com/) and Server Fault. Co-located with Stack Overflow’s [DevDays](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/devdays-2011-planning-begins/) event on the West Coast of the US, this conference will take place the day after DevDays wraps.

The topic this year will focus on techniques of high scalability. We plan to focus on tactical scalability; many companies don’t have the needs of Facebook or Google, but many of the problems and techniques still apply to most people involved in IT. The techniques to scale your infrastructure, and your ability to manage it apply to environments with less servers. We are going to try to get speakers from some of the big name companies in terms of scalability, but we will focus on talks that involve scalability issues that attendees will be able to apply in their own environments. ( More on this idea in [this blog post](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/scalability-isnt-about-the-size-of-your-equipment/).)

But we need your help naming this conference! We want to make sure it sounds like a conference for system administrators and "dev ops".  For reference, the url will be nameofthisconference.serverfault.com

If your name is chosen, you’ll get a free conference pass to attend!

Comment: Woooo +1 :) I take it this won't be a part of the traveling devdays?

Comment: @Mark: Well it is its own thing, but the current plan is that it will be the same venue and the day after the West Coast DevDays.

Comment: Do we have dates for that yet? Thems what approves travel budgets needs to know.

Comment: @sysadmin1138: Not set yet, hopefully in the next week or so.

Comment: On the west coast of where? I'm guessing you don't mean Western Australia.

Comment: @John Gardeniers: The US -- update the question.

Comment: Also, if this occurs during Blizzcon I'm going to be pissed!

Comment: There hasn't been much discussion about this conference. However, sounds like DevDays and ScaleDays have been cancelled: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/devdays-2011-is-cancelled/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ServerFault's ScaleDays**

(ScaleDay since it's only one day?)

URL would be  `scaledays.serverfault.com`

I hope we can enter more than once, this is just off the top of my head.

Comment: Think we are going to go with Scalability Day -- since it is derivative, you get the pass. Will send you an email we have an actual date etc...

Comment: Woo-hoo!    (stupid 15-char limit!)

Answer (score 5):

## KeepItUp

(or Keepin' It Up, if you like it better, and to make it at least 30 chars!)

Comment: I think I have to grudgingly vote for this one...

Comment: Sounds more like a reliability theme than a scale theme, though.

Comment: @Evan True, but you need scalability to keep up with ever-increasing traffic. Besides, I don't think overfitting the name to this year's theme is a good idea. The name might be reused in the future.

Comment: you can use a fake html tag (ex `<fake>`) as filler in Answers.

Answer (score 5):

BOFHConf would be the greatest ops conference ever.

Answer (score 4):

## Server Fault - Scalarity Ensues

URL: `b0rked.serverfault.com`

I'm not actually serious, but I really wanted to submit this.

Answer (score 3):

**ServerFault's HASIC** (**H**igh **A**vailability and **S**calability **I**nfrastructure **C**onference)

I should get extra points for the number of syllables used.

Comment: Well, suuuure, if you want people to actually know what we're there for.  But I don't like people knowing why I'm loitering in a hotel lobby, as it usually gets the cops called on me.  So more obfuscation please.

Comment: I though HASIC was somewhat obscure, and as a bonus, a pronounceable word.

Answer (score 3):

### OneToMany Days

Cunningly just off of "One too Many" for added humor value.

Comment: It's too bad I had to have this one explained to me...Which is my fault, not yours :)

Answer (score 3):

**ServerScale**

Apparently we're **boldly** going where many servers have gone before!

Answer (score 3):

SF's **L**ittle **I**nfrastructure  **B**ig **S**cale conference/convention

LIBS Con, if you will.  Or toss the "Con" part

Comment: In Australia, the Libs are a political party, so you'd be going to a political conference

Comment: @Mark heh I was kinda thinking about that too.  It could also be Little Infrastructure Large Scale, or some other arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

ServerFault presents:

- RedunDay
- Ops-Con
- CapaciCon
- Scale Tippers
- PerfCon
- Server Vault
- User Overflow

That's all I have right now

Answer (score 2):

## Server Fault - ScaleAvail - Scalable and Available

URL: `ScaleAvail.serverfault.com`

Answer (score 1):

**ServerFault's Scaling In Any Direction Conference**

**ServerFault's Scaling In All Dimensions**

or, even shorter (better for the url)

**ServerFault's Scaling Directions**  `scalingdirections.serverfault.com`

**ServerFault's Scaling Dimensions**  `scalingdimensions.serverfault.com`

Comment: Bolding it doesn't make it any better, you cheater!  :)

Comment: I'm just kidding *stop having ideas*!!!

Comment: At least I took out the obnoxious heading style that _some people_ have used!

Comment: Reminds me of a teenage pop group, a-la *Glee* (Don't judge me, my wife watches it and we only have one TV)

Comment: @Mark You're in a room full of sysadmins.  You're being judged regardless.  That admission just makes it all the sweeter.

Comment: @Holo - I've learned not to judge. Not after some of the things I've seen in people's inboxes when cleaning them out after they've hit their limits and they've asked me to purge their old messages.

Comment: @Mark Hahaha!  Too many replies to cialis adverts?

Comment: @Holo - if only... at least erectile disfunction is a serious medical condition that no man should be judged on. If that were all I'd seen, I think I'd be happy...

Answer (score 1):

**SFs Scale UP!**

**High Scale, Low Drag**

**Ziplining for Freedom**  <-- That just sounds cool

**Scalefest**

**ServerScale**

**Scalesplosion!**

**Less Fault, more Fail** (over)

Comment: Fixed the formatting for you.  :)  And I'll vote for ServerScale if you give it its own answer.

Comment: @ward You're a peach!

Answer (score 1):

Playing on the fault theme, Signal 11.

(signal 11 is SIGSEGV, more commonly known as a segmentation fault).

Comment: Huh? (stupid 15 character minimum)

Answer (score 1):

**ServerFault's AdminDay**

This name is similar to "Stack Overflow’s DevDays".

Since this conference will be co-located to the DevDays conference and this conference happens immediately after DevDays, using a similar name will leverage the popularity of the larger conference, and will show that these two communities are related.

Answer (score 0):

Server Con, because I like the whole con naming thing. =)