# Help Us Put On Stack Overflow DevDays 2011

Tags: discussion, conferences

Hey ServerFault Community -

As you guys probably know, we're bringing back Stack Overflow DevDays (along with a special 1 day ServerFault conference in SF on October 14th) and we need your help to make it happen!

To help make these events incredible, we're going to be putting together an awesome network package to carry around with us from city to city (think 15+ dual radio APs, hardcore switching and hardlines for 150 users).  The only hard part is that we need help setting it up and running it in various cities.

So we're looking for some experience networking folks to help us (1) setup the network and (2) administer it during the conference.  We're expecting everything to go pretty smoothly (fingers crossed) but want to be ready in case something crashes.

If you're interested, respond here or send me an email - alex (at) stackexchange (dot) com.  Please only respond for cities you live in or will be there for - unfortunately we can't help people with their travel to these various places.

And of course, we'll have all kinds of great goodies, swag, and thank you's for our helpers!

*When We Need Help*

**SF:** 2-3 people for setup on Oct 10th from 12p to 6p

**Sydney:** 2-3 people for setup on Oct 23rd from 12p to 6p & 1 person for the show on Oct. 25-26th

**London:** 2-3 people for setup on Nov 13th from 12p to 6p & 1 person for the show on Nov. 14th-15th

**Washington DC:** 2-3 people for setup on Dec 12th from 10a to 4p

Answer (score 1):

You can count on me for the DC event in December! If the SF event is still in SF (heh) I'll likely be there for that, though in an 'attending' capacity.

Comment: Yay!  That's great to hear.  Now just need to find out your favorite type of pizza :-D

Comment: @AlexMiller There is at least one more DC-local who I know is an SF regular.

Comment: that's great - any other good folks are always good to bring in

Comment: @AlexMiller That would be me.  I'm game for DC.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be willing to help with the DC event.  Should be a good learning experience if nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

> As you guys probably know, we're bringing back Stack Overflow DevDays (along with a special 1 day ServerFault conference in SF on October 14th) and we need your help to make it happen!

We knew there was going to be a conference, but I think this is the first anyone's heard of it since we [helped pick a name for the ServerFault conference.](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1518/server-fault-conference)  At least we finally know when it is.

Comment: Glad I can be the one to break the news.  But the rest of the team should have a lot more information coming out about the rest of the conference soon.  All I can say for now is that its going to be pretty darn cool.

Comment: The sooner the better, some of us have travel-submission deadlines.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 This just came in:  http://scalability.serverfault.com/

Comment: And the discount code is here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/devdays-is-back/

Comment: @Holocryptic Pinging my boss again on that one.

Comment: @sysadmin Cool, hope you can make it out there.

Answer (score 0):

Put me down for Sydney for 23rd October. I doubt I will be able to attend the conference though.

Comment: And put down you are (but only in the good way, not the insulting way or anything)

Comment: Well, everyone who has a grudge against me now knows when I'm going to be somewhere, now all they need is the Where and they can come and put me down in real life. Downside of using your real name on the intertubes I guess.